# Подсчитать количество четных элементов в случайно сформированном массиве Java

Tags: java, массивы

Всем доброго времени суток, ковыряю основы Java и наткнулся на такую задачу связанную с массивами:

> Создайте массив из 15 случайных целых чисел из отрезка [0;9].
> Выведите массив на экран. Подсчитайте сколько в массиве чётных
> элементов и выведете это количество на экран на отдельной строке.

Первую часть задания выполнил, во второй части решил схитрить и сделать вот так:

```java
public class Num2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
        Создайте массив из 15 случайных целых чисел из отрезка [0;9].
        Выведите массив на экран. Подсчитайте сколько в массиве чётных
        элементов и выведете это количество на экран на отдельной строке.
        */
        int[] arr1 = new int[15];
        int y = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            arr1[i] = ((int) (Math.random() * 9));
            if (arr1[i] == 2 || arr1[i] == 4 || arr1[i] == 6 || arr1[i] == 8) {
                y++;
            }

            System.out.print(arr1[i] + " ");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print(y);
        }
    }
}
```

Знаю что криво - косо и тупо, просто стало интересно почему не робит? Идея в том, что мы знаем все четные числа которые будут в заданном отрезке и можно поставить счетчик (y++) на появление числа в массиве, затем вывести просто этот счетчик в консоль.
Подскажите где логику нарушил?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё работает, просто надо вынести строку с выводом `y` за циклом:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    arr1[i] = ((int)(Math.random() * 9));
    if (arr1[i] == 2 || arr1[i] == 4 || arr1[i] == 6 || arr1[i] == 8 ) {
        y++;
    }

    System.out.print(arr1[i] + " ");
}
System.out.println();
System.out.print(y);
```

А для того чтобы выявить все чётные числа, легче сделать такое условие

```
if (arr1[i] % 2 == 0)
```

оно подразумевает, что если число делится на 2 без остатка, то оно чётное.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! 
Прописал код как Вы написали, выводит все равно криво:
7 0
7 0
3 0
3 0
5 0
2 1
4 2
3 2
8 3
6 4
7 4
0 5
8 6
0 7
8 8
 Выводит вот так, в столбик. Хотя по идее должна быть последовательность чисел и одно число, показывающее кол-во четных.

Comment: а, ой, тогда вам нужно вывести y за циклом

Comment: поправил ответ, чёт неправильно прочитал

Comment: Спасибо огромное) Уже тоже так поправил, все красиво получилось :)

Answer (score 3):

Ну во-первых, `(int)(Math.random() * 9)` сомнительная конструкция.  Например, число 9 вы <strike>получите только в случае, если `Math.random()` сгенерирует `1.0`, что очень маловероятно.</strike>  никогда не получите, так как `Math.random()` генерирует числа *строго меньше* 1.0, спасибо Эникейщику из комментариев.

Лучше заменить на простую конструкцию:

```
arr1[i] = random.nextInt(10);
```

Во-вторых, число 0 тоже является чётным.

В третьих, у вас вывод не читабелен, лучше выводите внутри цикла сгенерированные числа, а `y` выводите в самом конце один раз. Можно ещё выводить дополнительный текст, чтобы не путаться.

Comment: А какая запись корректная если нам нужно заполнить массив рандомными числами от 1 до 10?

Comment: Math.random() никогда не сгенерирует 1.0. Об этом написано в документации.

Comment: @НикитаХакерович, почитай javadoc к функции Random.nextInt(int n). Ответ: nextInt(10) + 1

Comment: @MikhailIonkin спасибо за наводку и ответ.

Comment: @Mikhailonkin Если не затруднит, пытаюсь поиграться с Random, почему идея ругается на random при такой записи? arr2[i] = random.nextInt(10) + 1; ? 
Если рандом с большой писать, ругается на nextInt

Comment: импорт util.Random сделал

Comment: Потому что вы не создали экземпляр наверное: `Random random = new Random();`

Answer (score 0):

```java
// заполняем массив случайными числами
int[] arr = IntStream.range(0, 15)
        .map(i -> (int) (Math.random() * 10))
        .toArray();

// считаем количество четных чисел
long even = Arrays.stream(arr).filter(i -> i % 2 == 0).count();

// выводим результат
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
// [2, 9, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 2, 8, 1, 6, 2, 7, 6]
System.out.println(even);
// 11
```